# What is a good credit or debit card that offers a reward with each transaction in the US?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, debit-card, reward-program

I am looking for a rewards card (credit or debit) where you can earn some number of cents (I've seen 10 or 20) per purchase that you charge to the card regardless of the amount.

Something similar to BofA's keep the change matching (which unfortunately only lasts 3 months) that offers a variable number of cents based on the difference to the next dollar would also work

Comment: Why are you limiting your search to those that give you 10/20 cents per sale and not a percentage. In most cases you would earn less cash back that way.

Comment: I already have one that gives me a percentage back but am looking for one that I can use on smaller purchases (like less than 10 bucks) that I make quite frequently.

Answer (score 3):

A website I (and Clark Howard) recommend for researching and comparing credit cards is [CardRating.com](http://www.cardratings.com). They recently did a best of story listing the best cards of various types including best cash-back cards: [Best Cards of 2011](http://www.cardratings.com/best-credit-cards-2011-editors-choice-1.html).

One thing that is very important to consider when comparing cash back cards is to look beyond the % cash back they advertise. Several of them cap the total amount of cash back you can get regardless of how much you spend. So take that in consideration. That is, if you get a 50% cash back card (fine print: on the first $3 of spending) that is not better than a 1% cash back card with unlimited rewards.

Most likely you are going to find the highest rewards on AMEX cards because they gouge the retailer on the transaction fees and that frees up more money for rewards points and cash back. However, that is also the reason that fewer place will take an AMEX that a Visa/MC so take that into consideration.

Comment: Nice site, John. Chase offers a card that has revolving categories that give 5%. Apr-Jun this year happens to be grocery stores. Seems I should buy the store's cash card to then spend in the following months. Limit though is $1500 in spending per qtr for $300/yr max.

Answer (score 0):

There are many credit cards that offer this type of rebate. Some flavors of American Express, and most if not all the ones from Discover. Individual banks offer Visa and Master cards with cash back.

These offers tend to be a percentage back from each transaction. The percentage can vary by the type of store or the amount you charge per year. the amount can vary for 0.25% to 3% or more.

There are terms and conditions, some will not give you the money if you miss a payment; others have maximums. Some companies will offer you additional ways to earn cash by using their site for online purchases, or by turning your points in for store credit at certain retailers.

These offers are different than the ones that offer airline miles, or hotel points.

Comment: "some number of cents per purchase that you charge to the card regardless of the amount." OP asked for a non-percent rebate/cash back. BOAs plan was a 'round to the next dollar' and after a brief time, it was your own money getting debited from your checking to move to savings.